# F1 is higher than accuracy using sklearn in keras callback. Something wrong?

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

I tried to make a custom callback to compute f1 and roc_auc in keras. I used sklearn to compute the f1 measure and roc_auc. Here's the code :

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, f1_score, roc_auc_score

class Measurement(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.acc = 0
        self.f1s = 0
        self.roc_auc = 0

def on_train_end(self, logs={}):
    y_true = []
    for y in self.validation_data[1]:
        for idx in range(2):
            if y[idx] == 1:
                y_true.append(idx)
    y_pred_temp = self.model.predict(self.validation_data[0])
    y_pred = []
    for y in y_pred_temp:
        for idx in range(2):
            if y[idx] > 0.49999 + K.epsilon():
                y_pred.append(idx)
    self.acc = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
    self.f1s = f1_score(y_true, y_pred)
    self.roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred)
    return

def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
    return

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    return

def on_batch_begin(self, batch, logs={}):
    return

def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
    return
```

My dataset amount is so imbalanced, i have 2 classes, the 1st class data is only 33% of the entire data. So i used, `StratifiedKFold` to mitigate the problem of that imbalanced data itself. But, the final result yields a lower accuracy in comparison with the F1 value. I never saw something like that. My professor also said there might be something wrong, but i chose to believe that it is normal, since the negative class(1st class) amount is a lot lesser than the positive class, which will result to a lower true negative value, and make the accuracy lower. Any thought? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its very hard to say unless you post the actual values and data.

Comment: The data is actually a confidential asset, all i can tell you is that it comes in form of texts, and it has 2 classes, with a distribution 33% for the first class and 67% for the second class, which means the data is imbalanced in terms of amount. And the result is as follow : 
`ACCURACY: 84.28%`
`F1: 87.79%`

Comment: Any idea @VivekKumar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally tried to switch the classes label, and it gives a smaller F1. So the phenomenon i described in the question is possibly because of the low amount of the negative class which result to a lower true negative value, which is not considered in F1 but considered in accuracy.